# Can I overwrite OceanWP theme's CSS which is based on Elementor in a custom plugin where I am using Bootstrap 4?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4, elementor

I am using the WordPress theme [OceanWP](https://oceanwp.org/) and [Elementor](https://elementor.com/) page builder.

Now I created a custom plugin that creates a form and generates a shortcode for it to be used on the front-end using `Bootstrap 4`.

The problem is that when displaying the form on the front-end the Bootstrap CSS enqueued gets mixed up with that of the theme's CSS.

How can I prevent that?

Comment: It might work if you add custom classes to your elements of the form or even the entire form. That way no css will be applied to them.

Comment: I am also running into this issue. I have tried several different attempts for a solution and still have not discovered how to override OceanWPs css styles, with those of my plugin.